# Why was my post deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451079/how-can-i-stop-my-mac-running-10-13-from-filling-up-its-swap-space) about how to diagnose a weird swap issue with my Mac. I received some unhelpful advice from someone who didn't understand what the difference between VM and swap was, so I decided to add a bounty to it (after the person who tried to help me presumably got upset that he was wrong and downvoted my post). I've come back after the holidays just to discover that it has been deleted. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on the „deleted“ link on top you get https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/roomba which explains the various reasons posts may get deleted automatically. In your case the „score < 0 and no answer after 30 days“ rule applied.

If still relevant, you should be able to undelete the question yourself.

Comment: I did vote to undelete, but it also appears I cannot update it with new information. Personally I don't believe just one person should be able to downvote a question and have it get deleted.

Comment: @At0mic it got deleted because it was downvoted *and* didn‘t gather any answers. I can undelete it but you still may want to edit some more details in to increase the chance for answers.

Comment: I cannot edit it, as it is deleted.

Comment: @At0mic I undeleted it. You only have a short time window to edit though, the system will keep autodeleting.